# C# Background Worker only reports progress after entire processing is complete

Tags: c#, .net

I have this issue with my background worker where it only fires after my task is completed and not during. I have made sure to segment the progress properly but its still not firing. I'm not sure what else I can do.

Here is my code:

```
private int segmentHalf = 0;
private int segmentFull = 0;
public AutoMaticOne()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

}

private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var backgroundWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    List<PrintObject> pol = new List<PrintObject>();

    var program = programsData.Get(programSelectionInput.Text);
    var fields = fieldsData.GetAllByTaskId(program.Id);
    pol = printerData.Load(Input, program.Name,fields,program.Delimiter);
    pol = pol.OrderBy(x => x.FilePath).ToList();
    if (pol != null)
    {
        for(int i =0;i<pol.Count();i++)
        {
            segmentHalf = (((i + 1) / pol.Count()) * 100) / 2;
            segmentFull = segmentHalf * 2;
            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(segmentHalf);
            print.Process(pol[i].FilePath, pol[i].PrinterDriver);
            infoInput.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                infoInput.Text = infoInput.Text + "\r\n" + pol[i].FileName + " - " + pol[i].PrinterDriver;
            });
            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(segmentFull);
        }
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender,
            ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Change the value of the ProgressBar to the BackgroundWorker progress.
    ProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    ProgressBarLabel.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
}

private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,
    RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    InputDirectory.Enabled = true;
    OutputDirectory.Enabled = true;
    InputDirectoryButton.Enabled = true;
    OutputDirectoryButton.Enabled = true;
    MessageBox.Show("Task has been Completed, Output files can be found at " + OutputDirectory.Text, "Task Completed");
    Start.Enabled = true;
}
```

When I start with 10 files, it seems fine. But when it loads something like 1000, then it only reports the progress at the end.

SegmentHalf and Full are declared above the constructor

Comment: Could it be a case of the UI not updating/repainting? Try executing a `this.Update()` in the `backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged` method.

Comment: `(i + 1) / pol.Count()` is likely to be `0` most of the time. But that doesn't explain "with 10 files, it seems fine"

Comment: Hint: most questions about "my progressbar isn't working" come down to a misunderstanding about integer division.

Comment: @HenkHolterman When I calculated it, it should get something with a decimal. I understand that I'm using integers which will round the number up. Also, despite me calculating, why is my segmenthalf and full always 0?

Comment: try once with commenting this code block `infoInput.Invoke...`

Comment: @er-sho infoInput.Invoke isn't the issue. That only displays text to my Inputbox

Comment: @JianYA Invoke *is* a serious issue. That's what the *Progress* event is for. That code will block until it can run on the UI thread. You can pass an `object` variable in the `ReportProgress` call. Use that to pass the file and printer names

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - you are right but in this case there is nothing inside the delegate that could block. So changing this would be a small optimization at best. Using BeginInvoke instead of Invoke would help a lot too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `i < pol.Count - 1`, `(i + 1) / pol.Count` will be `0`. Integer division truncates towards 0. Your code will execute `0 * 100` for all except the last file.

You can fix it like this:

```
//segmentHalf = (((i + 1) / pol.Count()) * 100) / 2;
  segmentHalf = (((i + 1) * 100) / pol.Count) / 2;
```